# Linux terminal v.s. Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

What's the difference between running an application in a Linux terminal and Eclipse?

I created a GUI program which runs fine in Eclipse, i.e., build the program in Eclipse and start by pressing "Ctrl + F11". But once I tried to start the program in a terminal, the program fails to start.

I am using GNU C++ compiler, Fedora 16, Eclipse Indigo.

Thanks.

Comment: could you be more specific about the error?

Comment: Usually, when applications run in terminal and fails it should print some errors. Do you have any errors in terminal after run application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major differences are probably the working directory and some environment variables that might make things work. There is really nothing else to starting a program that anything like Eclipse could be doing.

What exactly happens when you try to start it in a terminal? We might be able to help you more if you tell us what, if anything, is printed out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am migrate my application from Windows to Linux, and got the working directory wrong, the Linux program is reading some old configuration files.